# Proving that cross product squared is an inner product determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant, cross-product

Prove that: $\left \| \vec{v}\times \vec{w}\right \|^2=det\begin{pmatrix}
<\vec{v},\vec{v}> & <\vec{v},\vec{w}>\\ 
<\vec{w},\vec{v}> & <\vec{w},\vec{w}>
\end{pmatrix}$

What is the relation between cross and inner product so that I can conclude the above equality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove this Gram determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805196/how-to-prove-this-gram-determinant)

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out

$\left \| \vec{v}\times \vec{w} \right \|^2=\left \| \vec{v} \right \|^2\left \| \vec{w} \right \|^2-<\vec{v},\vec{w}>^2=\left \| \vec{v} \right \|^2\left \| \vec{w} \right \|^2-<\vec{v},\vec{w}><\vec{w},\vec{v}>=<\vec{v},\vec{v}><\vec{w},\vec{w}>-<\vec{v},\vec{w}><\vec{w},\vec{v}>=\begin{vmatrix}
<\vec{v},\vec{v}> & <\vec{v},\vec{w}>\\ 
<\vec{w},\vec{v}> & <\vec{w},\vec{w}>
\end{vmatrix}$