# Slick proof of cross product identities

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product, exterior-algebra

The cross product between vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ obeys two pleasant identities (sometimes named after Lagrange), namely

- $a\times(b\times c)=b(a\cdot c)-c(a\cdot b)$
- $(a\times b)\cdot(c\times d)=(a\cdot c)(b\cdot d)-(a\cdot d)(b\cdot c)$.

The first one can be proved by invoking multilinearity and thus reducing oneself to a tedious check when $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. The second one can be deduced from the first using properties of the triple product.

I am looking for some slick/conceptual proof of the two identities (or one of them); maybe exterior algebra has something to tell us?

Comment: You know levi-cevita symbol?

Comment: Yes, I forgot mentioning that alternative. But using it means invoking the identity $\epsilon _{ijk}\epsilon_{imn}=\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn}-\delta_{jn}\delta_{km}$, which looks too magical to me, so I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely approach this from the perspective of exterior algebra. Indeed, the part of your question relating to your first identity [has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305285/49610), so for the coordinate-free, exterior algebra proof of that, please take a look at [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/482498/49610) to the earlier question. So, let me know turn to your second identity. Before continuing, let me recycle some background and notation from my old answer.

> Recall that if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional inner product space, then the
>   *Hodge star* is a linear isomorphism $\ast : \bigwedge^k V \to \bigwedge^{n-k} V$ for each $0 \leq k \leq n$, satisfying the
>   following:
>
> 1. for $v$, $w \in V$, $\langle v,w\rangle \omega = v \wedge \ast w$ for $\omega = \ast 1$ the generator of $\bigwedge^n V$ satisfying
>      $\omega = e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$ for any orthonormal basis
>      $\{e_k\}$ of $V$ with the appropriate orientation (e.g., the volume
>      form in $\bigwedge^n (\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast$);
> 2. in particular, $\ast \ast = \operatorname{Id}$ when $n$ is odd.
>
> Also, recall that the inner product on $\bigwedge^k V$ is given by $$\langle v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k, w_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge w_k \rangle = \det(\langle v_i,w_j \rangle). $$
>
> So, suppose that $V$ is $3$-dimensional, in which case we can define
>   the cross product of $a$, $b \in V$ by $$a \times b := \ast (a\wedge b).$$

Now, let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Then
$$
 \langle a \times b, c \times d \rangle \omega = \langle \ast (a \wedge b), \ast (c \wedge d) \rangle \omega \\
= \ast (a \wedge b) \wedge \ast \ast (c \wedge d) \\
= \ast (a \wedge b) \wedge (c \wedge d)\\
= (-1)^{1 \cdot 2} (c \wedge d) \wedge \ast (a \wedge b)\\
= \langle c \wedge d, a \wedge b \rangle\omega \\
= \langle a \wedge b, c \wedge d \rangle\omega\\
= \begin{vmatrix} \langle a,c \rangle & \langle a,d \rangle \\ \langle b,c \rangle & \langle b,d \rangle \end{vmatrix}\omega\\
= (\langle a,c \rangle \langle b,d \rangle - \langle a,d \rangle \langle b,c \rangle)\omega,
$$
as was required. Observe, in particular, that the right-hand side of your second identity looks like a $2 \times 2$ determinant because once you've unpacked all relevant definitions, it really *is* a $2 \times 2$ determinant, namely the inner product
$$
\langle a \wedge b, c \wedge d \rangle := \begin{vmatrix} \langle a,c \rangle & \langle a,d \rangle \\ \langle b,c \rangle & \langle b,d \rangle \end{vmatrix}
$$ 
of the bivectors $a \wedge b$, $c \wedge d \in \bigwedge^2 \mathbb{R}^3$.